# Как искать сразу несколько подстрок через find в python?

Tags: python, find

```
text = "ужас вот ты достал"
textsplit = text.split()
for list in textsplit:
    search = list.find("ужас")
    if search != -1:
        numbersofletter = len(list)
        textreplace = text.replace(list, numbersofletter * "*")
        print(textreplace)
```

Мне надо написать программу которая будет заменять все маты на "*". Я смог сделать чтобы оно замазывало слово "ужас" (мат заменен), а мне надо чтобы оно еще и замазывало "достал", подскажите как через find искать сразу несколько слов? Создать функцию или что?

Comment: Используйте регулярные выражения

Comment: либо проход циклом по списку матов

Comment: И не называйте свою переменную `list`, вы так скрываете родной тип питона.

Comment: Товарищи благодарю, буду пробовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы через множества делал (стало любопытно, так что и сделал) - комментарии в коде поясняющие. Тут тогда цикл не нужен, чтобы по всем матам проходить.

```
text = "ужас вот ты достал"
# Множество с плохими словами
bad_words = {"ужас", "достал", "класс"}
# Преобразуем строку в множество
textsplit = set (text.split())
# Определяем все плохие слова
result = bad_words & textsplit
textreplace = text
# Заменяем все плохие слова последовательно
for word in result:
    if word in text:
        numbersofletter = len(word)
        textreplace = textreplace.replace(word, numbersofletter * "*")
print(textreplace)
```

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь!

Comment: textreplace = text  могу узнать зачем эта строчка?

Comment: @ГрогуЙодович, вы же `text` не хотите изменять, как я понял, а замен может быть несколько в цикле нижнем. Попробуйте, что получится, если без этой строки использовать редакцию `textreplace = text.replace(word, numbersofletter * "*")` при двух плохих словах и более.

Comment: Кажись я понял, спасибо